# Изменить позицию матриц (Старый OpenGL)

Tags: opengl

Есть вот такой код:

```
void Object::add()
{
    float projection[16]{};
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
 
    float modelview[16]{};
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
 
    Object::projection.insert(Object::projection.end(), begin(projection), end(projection));
    Object::modelview.insert(Object::modelview.end(), begin(modelview), end(modelview));
}
```

Он записывает данные матриц проекции и model-view в массив, для того чтобы потом я мог загрузить эти матрицы и дорисовать то что мне нужно.

Я попытался изменить этот код на

```
void Object::add(float offsetX, float offsetY, float offsetZ)
{
    float projection[16]{};
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
 
    projection[12] = projection[12] + offsetX;
    projection[13] = projection[13] + offsetY;
    projection[14] = projection[14] + offsetZ;
 
    float modelview[16]{};
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
 
    modelview[12] = modelview[12] + offsetX;
    modelview[13] = modelview[13] + offsetY;
    modelview[14] = modelview[14] + offsetZ;
 
    Object::projection.insert(Object::projection.end(), begin(projection), end(projection));
    Object::modelview.insert(Object::modelview.end(), begin(modelview), end(modelview));
}
```

Для того чтобы иметь возможность по желанию корректировать расположение перед сохранением в вектор, но это даёт странный результат. При движении камеры игрока, начинает изменяться и позиция:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNHu2dAjv24.

Если менять только model-view, то получается примерно похожий эффект:
https://youtu.be/nAHGmnqe3x4.

Я не могу использовать `glTranslatef` перед сохранением матриц, поскольку в таком случае изменится и позиция рисуемого на данный момент игрой объекта. Я мог бы добавить глобальные переменные со значениями смещения и уже после загрузки сохранённых матриц вызывать `glTranslatef`, но хотелось бы решить эту задачу без дополнительных переменных, редактируя сами массивы перед из записью в вектор. Как правильно сделать то что мне нужно?

Comment: Как я понял, матрицу как-то нужно умножать, а не "в тупую" прибавлять offset

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Зачем вы вообще прибавлять эти offsets? Вы хотите «корректировать расположение». Расположение чего? Объекта, который вы рисуете? Если да, тогда почему не формируете для него его собственную матрицу model-view?

Comment: Дело в том, что я ничего не рисую, а перехватываю определенный момент, когда игра рисует то что мне нужно и "запоминаю" позицию (при помощи сохранения двух текущих матриц PROJECTION и MODELVIEW) для того чтобы дорисовать обводку когда игра закончит рисование всех объектов. А offset мне нужен для того чтобы перед тем как я добавлю матрицы в вектор "откорректировать" позицию, чтобы координаты указывали ровно на центр того что мне нужно. Не пытайтесь понять для чего мне это, просто помогите с тем, как это реализовать. Мне нужна возможность добавлять смещения по X Y Z.

Comment: Например, игра рисует сундук, я в свою очередь, магическим образом определяю что рисуется именно сундук и сохраняю текущие матрицы в векторы. Потом, когда игра закончит рисование всего, я пробегаюсь по этим векторам и дорисовываю обводку. Но, дело в том, что не всегда сохраненные матрицы указывают на самый центр объекта, бывает так что они с какого-то края. Мне нужно рисовать линию к этим объектам и получается так что линия ведёт не в центр объекта а к его краю. Я хотел исправить это, добавив offset'ы.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ дал пользователь zayats80888 на cyberforum

```
void translate(float * m, float x, float y, float z)
{
    float m3[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        m3[i] = m[i] * x + m[i + 4] * y + m[i + 8] * z + m[i + 12];
    std::memcpy(m + 12, m3, sizeof(m3));
}
```